# how to order by numeric and character

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-orderby

[**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/edKXTcQ8EoiP49tYT90q?p=preview)

I have a `ng-repeat`, and in the drop down there are the following values.

```
Up to 6 months
From 13 to 24 months
Higher than 24 months
From 6 to 12 months
```

and I need to sort the values like the following

```
//following is the expected output
// Up to 6 months
//From 6 to 12 months
//From 13 to 24 months
//Higher than 24 months




$scope.items = [{name: 'Up to 6 months', id: 30 },{ name: 'From 13 to 24 months', id: 27 },{ name: 'Higher than 24 months', id: 50 },{ name: 'From 6 to 12 months', id: 50 }];
```

Comment: Can you not put a sort order in every item and then sort by that sort order?

Comment: on what basis I need to sort each item

Comment: on the basis of the name value's position in  the comma separated string "Up to 6 months,From 6 to 12 months,From 13 to 24 months,Higher than 24 months". I hope this is not how it is stored in the data base - how would you handle a request to change "Highter than 24 months" to "More than two years"?

Answer (score 1):

Your name field is not formatted text you cannot do order by on name, add one field like follows which will fill the field value with sorted criteria. An example sort function is given here:

```
$scope.items.sort(
function(a,b) {
// Change the logic based on your criteria
return (/*Your criteria*/) ? 1 : 0);
} 
);
```

Your data then will be like follows:

```
$scope.items = [{name: 'Up to 6 months',sort:0, id: 30 },{ name: 'From 13 to 24 months',sort:1, id: 27 },{ name: 'Higher than 24 months',sort:3, id: 50 },{ name: 'From 6 to 12 months', sort:4, id: 50 }];
```

Use the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:['sort','id']">{{item.name}}-{{item.id}}</div>
```

Comment: seems better but the order is a bit changed

Comment: //From 13 to 24 months
/ Up to 6 months
//From 6 to 12 months
//Higher than 24 months

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: you have maintained another sort id..., the values are coming from db... so I need to maintain another column.... it is difficult

Comment: yes. you have to create a key based on your name field. As the name are not alphabetically ordered, there is no way to do order by on that field, you have to create a key.

Comment: You need not to maintain another column, Just make a function, that can fill the sort value, like $scope.items[0].sort = (some sort function)

Answer (score 0):

Your Items will be load like this,

```
 $scope.selectedItem = { name: 'two', id: 27 };
 $scope.items = [{name: 'Up to 6 months',sort:1, id: 30 },{ name: 'From 13 to 24 months',sort:3, id: 27 },{ name: 'Higher than 24 months',sort:4, id: 50 },{ name: 'From 6 to 12 months', sort:2, id: 50 }];
```

ng-repeat

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem">
   <option ng-repeat="item in items  | orderBy:['sort']" value={{item.id}}>
    {{item.name}}
   </option>
</select>
```